# HTML encoding happening with Gulp on Windows

Tags: utf-8, gulp, node-modules

I have created a Gulp plugin called [php-include-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-include-html), which scans php files in Gulp and processes include and require statements to inline HTML snippets.

The snippet of the gulpfile looks like this...

```js
var gulp = require("gulp");
var pump = require("pump");
var phpinc = require("php-include-html");

gulp.task("php",function(cb) {
  pump([
    gulp.src("*.php"),
    phpinc({verbose:true}),
    gulp.dest("build")
  ],cb);
});
```

This is a snippet from the php file before processing...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">
  <head>
    <title>Emma Malik's Official Website - Legal</title>
```

And here's the same snippet after processing...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">
  <head>
    <title>Emma Malik&amp;s Official Website - Legal</title>
```

As you can see, the apostrophe has been HTML encoded.  However, it doesn't seem to be all ampersands, just some of them, and some other characters as well, such as > to > but again, not all of them.

All the way through my plugin, this remains an apostrophe, it seems to be the gulp.dest rewriting the file which somehow converts it.

Things I've tried...

1. Stripping the UTF-8 BOM from the source file (strip-bom and
   strip-bom-buf)
2. Adding the UTF-8 BOM to the destination file (gulp-header)
3. Using string manipulation instead of String.replace
4. Converting the destination contents to UTF-8 (gulp-convert-encoding)
5. Decoding after my plugin before gulp.dest (gulp-html-entities)
6. Using vinyl-file

Has anyone seen anything like this before, or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

False alarm, it turns out that it is actually the "gulp-sri-hash" plugin, which runs after mine, which is doing this.  I need to investigate further as to what exactly is causing this, but at least I've figured out it's not me!